# Cross worksheet Sql query taking time?

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have around 10 thousand records(rows) in one sheet A and around a thousand in sheet B. Both have 5 columns. I need to filter sheet A using column filters and then find everything which is not on sheet B using the ID in both the sheets. Eg: Sheet A has 10 thousand , apply filter and it comes to 1200. Now select the records which are not in Sheet B. I have written a query for it.

```
  rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [A$] WHERE ([Class]<>'Other' OR...) AND ([Sub Class]='Good' OR...) AND [ID] NOT IN (SELECT [B$].ID FROM [B$])"
```

Query runs extremely slow and I don't know if I will even get any answer waiting hours, may be it is wrong too. I checked and found that if I exclude the last AND , the query executes in a second. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use a SQL query within an Excel workbook if you're not querying a database? Wouldn't VLOOKUP be much simpler?

Comment: I don't as how can I use Vlookup to apply filters and then match. Can you give a little idea and then I should be able to do it.